# Why does Piston render a blank window on macOS?

Tags: macos, rust, rust-piston

I am trying to run the Piston [Getting Started Tutorial](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/Piston-Tutorials/tree/master/getting-started) on my MacBook Pro. When running the example with `cargo run`, only a blank window appears with no rendering:

[image: a blank window with no rendering]

Why are the graphics are not rendering?

Edit: For anyone in a similar situation, deleting my Cargo.lock file and rebuilding the example fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors? Is there anything in the console (stdout/stderr)? What do you expect from us not providing us with anything? :) We can only say that "something has happened".

Comment: There is nothing being printed to the console. I've tried making print statements for many of the variables in the code and checking to see if each section is being accessed. None of the variables seemed to have unusual values and each section of the code was being run during the while loop. I've tried specifying OpenGL::V2_1, OpenGL::V3_2, OpenGL::V3_3, and OpenGL::V4_0. Nothing seems of out the ordinary except the lack of graphics rendering. I get the same issue when trying to run the project https://github.com/a5huynh/defender-game.

Comment: However all of the piston examples at https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston-examples work correctly and render graphics.